# How to keep the title of a website as original when the website loaded and auto-add '(1 message)' in the front title in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There are some websites that will auto add '(1 message)' in the front title, and I want to remove the characters added.

I try to use 'observe' to the element title to keep it as original in a Tampermonkey script, but some pages work, some pages with the same host do not.

Even it seems that it doesn't get the real original title of the page that run-at the document-start, and it will work one time after the title changes again.

So that means that the page title keeps adding '(1 message)' no matter when the title deletes '(1 message)'.

Is there another way to keep the title as original or did I miss something in the following code?

```
// identify an element to observe
var originalInnerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML; 

var elementToObserve = window.document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];

// create a new instance of 'MutationObserver' named 'observer',
// passing it a callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
    console.log(mutationsList);
    var titleElement=document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
    titleElement.innerHTML = originalInnerHTML;
    observer.disconnect();//stop the MutationObserver
});

// call 'observe' on that MutationObserver instance,
// passing it the element to observe, and the options object
observer.observe(elementToObserve, {characterData: true, childList: true, attributes: true, subtree: true});
```

Comment: Is this in an extension or something?

Comment: *"...and it will work one time after the title changes again."* You're turning off the observer (`disconnect`) the first time there's a change, so it's not going to observe the *next* change.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your attention to this question. I set it in a Tampermonkey script.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep, as in the post, the title will auto change the title to auto add the '1 message', It will no longer stop.

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing The Observer

The observer should work. The thing that jumps out is that you're disconnecting the observer the first time it sees a change. So it won't see the *next* change. To fix that, remove the call to `disconnect`.

### If The Observer Doesn't Work

If you fix that but find that the observer isn't reliable (which would surprise me), then I'd take a simple-minded approach to it:

```
const originalTitle = document.title;
setInterval(() => {
    document.title = originalTitle;
}, 100);
```

That will grab the title when the code runs and then repeatedly replace the old title with it, every 10th of a second. (Or make it every fourth of a second — 250ms  — or whatever.) Note that browsers will de-prioritize timers in inactive tabs, but that should affect their code updating the title as much as your code updating the title.

---

(Side note: I've used [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) there, as it's simpler than the `getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML` approach.)

Comment: Thank you so much again. It is a nice solution to this title change problem as I also tried a long time ago by the second one, and there is still a problem that the title keeps adding '(1 message)', then the title will keep flashing. Sorry that the websites are in China, and you may not test that website.

Comment: @lyscop - I don't think there's anything you can do to **prevent** the title from being changed, which is what triggers the tab flashing. Sorry!

Comment: Yep, it seems can't prevent it for its js files made this. I am glad that you help me. Ummm, just title flashes and this is the result of using the 'observe' on the title element. https://i.vgy.me/NXeg8x.gif

Comment: @lyscop - It's not the result of using `observe`, it's the result of changing the title.